# Yii - Pass model ID into a view from CButtonColumn image

Tags: php, yii

Alright, still new to Yii I am attempting to create a button in a column of CGridView.  This button, when clicked, will take the user to the "view.php" page and display the information of the node they clicked on by passing in its ID.

I am frustrated that I cannot figure out how to simply add a link to the image that will direct my users.   Here are some snippets of the code I have been working on for the past couple of days.

#### index.php

```
<?php echo CHtml::beginForm(); ?>
<?php
$pageSize = Yii::app()->user->getState('pageSize', Yii::app()->params['defaultPageSize']);
$this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
    'id' => 'nodes-grid',
    'dataProvider' => $model->search(),
    'filter' => $model,
    'columns' => array(
        array(
            'class' => 'CButtonColumn',
            'template' => '{restart}',
            'buttons' => array
            (
                'restart' => array
                (
                    'label'=>'Restart this node',
                    'imageUrl'=>Yii::app()->baseUrl.'/images/refresh.png',
                    'options'=>array('id'=>'NB_bounce_Button'),
                    'url'=>array('view', 'id'=>$model->id),
                )
            ),
        ),
        /* 'id', */
        'name',
        'url',
        'description',
        'node_type',
        'last_bounced',
        //..
```

#### NodeBouncerController.php (View action)

```
/**
 * Displays a particular model.
 * @param integer $id the ID of the model to be displayed
 */
public function actionView($id) {
    $this->render('view', array(
        'model' => $this->loadModel($id),
    ));
}
```

[image: Current view of Node Bouncer page]

The button is on the left. (Refresh green arrow)

What am I doing wrong?  More specifically, am I using the buttons of CButtonColumn incorrectly?  If so, how may I fix this?

My company uses:  Yii v1.1.8.r3324

---

**EDIT: [8/10/15]**

It seems I may have been overcomplicating it.  What I needed was to simply have an image-link that when clicked went to the view for that particular node that was clicked.  Well, Gii auto-generates the particular view I needed and the code associated with it (as seen above).

My fix was to do away with the over complicated mess that I had and keep it simple.  Use the template already provided for "view" and just alter it to my needs.

Like so:

```
/* 'id', */
        array(
          'class'=>'CButtonColumn',
          'template'=>'{view}',
          'buttons' => array
              (
                'view' => array
                    (
                        'label'=>'Restart this node',
                        'imageUrl'=>Yii::app()->baseUrl.'/images/refresh.png',
                        'options'=>array
                                    (
                                        'id'=>'NB_bounce_Button'
                                    )
                    )
              ),
        ),
        'name',
        'url',
        'description',
        'node_type',
        'last_bounced',
        //....
```

It would be nice to know how to do this manually but I needed something to simply work for now and expand on it later for work.

Comment: Please correct the last line of your question. The latest stable version of yii 1 is **1.1.16**.

Comment: That may be the latest stable version of yii, however that is not the version my company is choosing to use.  Why they wish to use an older or unstable version, is beyond me, but it is what I have to work with.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is url of the button. Because you did not include **controllerID** in the url. You should use this:

```
'url' => 'Yii::app()->createUrl("nodeBouncer/view", "id"=>$model->id)';
```

For creating url in yii, usually you should follow this pattern:
**contollerID/actionID**